# WMV Video formats not supported in SharePoint 2019 Page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, video

I am using HTML5 Video player to play videos in SharePoint 2019 page. It plays videos only mp4, ogg and WebM formats.
Is there a way to play other formats using any other approach except Silverlight?

Comment: Stupid question, but why not just convert them since the built-in player doesn't support it?

Comment: Could you suggest another way to directly play WMV files in SharePoint pages? Or maybe share a link which confirms that WMV formats are not supported by SharePoint at all? As per this link they are - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-video-audio-or-images-to-a-classic-page-b5220c61-e56a-40fd-8754-d06a2e38b492

Comment: Not sure why converting it wouldn't be an option... Since WMV consists of multiple codecs, perhaps the HTML5 player doesn't support the specific codec used by your WMV.